# If $|f_i(x_1) - f_i(x_2)| \leq a$ for all $f_i$'s, does $ | \min_i f_i(x_1) - \min_i f_i(x_2) | \leq a? $

Tags: real-analysis

Given a set $X$, $x_1, x_2 \in X$, and $f_i: X \to \mathbb R, i=1,\dots, m$.

If $|f_i(x_1) - f_i(x_2)| \leq a$ for all $f_i, i=1,\dots, m$, does
$$
| \min_i f_i(x_1) - \min_i f_i(x_2) | \leq a?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\left|\min_i f_i(x_1)-\min_i f_i(x_2)\right|>a$. WLOG let $\min_i f_i(x_2)< \min_i f_i(x_1)$ and let $1$ be the minimizing index for $\min_i f_i(x_2)$. Then $$f_1(x_1) \ge \min_i f_i(x_1)> a+\min_i f_i(x_2)=a+f_1(x_2),$$
a contradiction.